# why do we need componentScan in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

This question might be trivial but still i'm unable to find a good reason or best practice towards `@ComponentScan` in Spring

DI works just by self annotating the class then why do we need `@ComponentScan`

What is the best practice towards this?

Comment: What do you specifically mean when you say self annotating? Do you mean adding stereotype annotations to classes? Why do you believe DI works just by self annotating?

Comment: I tried using autowire for classes that i had annotated with as service and repository. I didnt had to pass thier packages to componentscan. Infact i didnt had componentscan. It still worked. So i beleived that marely self annotation is sufficient for DI. Although m nt sure if m right. I mean there must be a good reason to choose componentscan when DI works just with slef annotation

Comment: What did your configuration look like? Spring boot?

Comment: Yes spring boot

Comment: and what configuration were you using with spring boot? I'd ask yourself how did spring boot find these classes with annotations and how did it register them as beans

Comment: Well thats what surprises me. I have multiple modules in my application. I'm using maven to build them so i have all classes in my classpath. So when i use Autowire on any class i get the object. I dont know how it works but it does and thats why i'm surprised that if it is possible then what good componentscan is doing?

Comment: What does your spring boot configuration look like? Are you using @SpringBootApplication? If so you are using componentscanning. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html. What I'm getting you may be using componetnscanning whether you know about it or not.

Comment: Well this make sense. But if `@springbootapplication` includes componentscan then which all packages does it take? Does it consider any package which doesnt fit inside package of springapplication class? Like if i have main method in pkg a.b.c and i want to have repository on b.c.d will it work?

Comment: it will scan from the package, where the `@Springbootapplication` present

Answer (score 4):

`@ComponentScan` tells Spring in which packages you have annotated classes which should be managed by Spring.

Spring needs to know which packages contain spring beans, otherwise you would have to register each bean individually in(xml file). This is the use of `@ComponentScan.`

Take a simple example, you have a class and annotated with `@Controller` in a package `package com.abc.xyz;` , you have to tell the spring to scan this package for `Controller` class, if spring didn't scan this package, then spring will not identifies it as a controller class.

Suppose if your dealing with configuration file,

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.xyz">` 
like this,

When spring loads the xml file, this tag will search the all the classes present in the `package com.abc.xyz`, so any of the class containing `@controller, @Repository @Service` etc.., if it found then spring will register these annotated class in the bean factory.

Suppose if your using spring boot application,

Then your spring-boot application is annotated with The`@SpringBootApplication`.

`@SpringBootApplication` annotation is equivalent to using `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` with their default attributes.

One more point if you didn;t specify the base package name in `@ComponentScan`,
it will scan from the package, where the `@Springbootapplication` present

Comment: I know that. But my question is, that spring is able to identify classes with selfannotation only. Then why do we need componentscan?

Comment: _spring is able to identify classes with selfannotation only_ means I didn;t get

Comment: I can annotate my controller class with @controller anf i dont need to pass its package to componentscan. It still works. Even service repository etc all works without scan as well

Comment: So basically your telling `@Controller` class is working fine without `@ComponentScan` annotation or `<context:component-scan base-package="===">` this tag inside spring config file.

Comment: Yes. In my spring btoot application i dont have config file or component scan. I do have config class annotated with `@configuration` same for controller, service and repository

Comment: Then your spring-boot application is annotated with The `@SpringBootApplication.` `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is equivalent to using `@Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan` with their default attributes:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161869/discussion-between-arvind-katte-and-kumar-gaurav).